# Read a binary file in Javascript and make a qr code

Tags: javascript, file, binary, qr-code

I need to read a file, which has no extension, in a web page and then encode this file in a QR code in binary mode.

In order to encode binary I found this library and I think is good: https://github.com/nayuki/QR-Code-generator/blob/master/javascript/qrcodegen.js

But for the first part, read a file and don't modify it or encode it as a text or something else, I am unable to understand how to do it.

What is the best choice? A success could be just read that file and allow the page to download the file I had read in order to check that is the same file.

Comment: you need to give us something you have done . not just asking what can i do

Comment: I haven't done anything, i wrote a page in which i have a file selector and a button. I broke my mind finding that qr code library (is difficult to find a qr code js library that supports binary encoding and is well documented). For the reading stuff, i think this is the way (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsArrayBuffer), but now i am unable to get a working script. I read a lot about this, but i find old and deprecated code. I'm just asking a library.

Comment: It is rather unclear what you are trying to ask here.  Where is this file you are trying to read coming from?  And what kind of file is it that you are trying to make a QR code from?  This seems like a strange thing to do, since QR codes generally can only store around 3kb or less of data.....

Comment: And if, as your recent comment suggests, all you are trying to do is get recommendations for a library, you should know that that kind of question is off topic for this site.

Comment: I need to encode an encrypted file that is less than 600 byte

Comment: I have readed in stackoverflow a lot of old discussions about this task, i haven't written any line of code, just readed about all kind of possibilities, but no one working

Comment: Your comment is still misleading though.... you say "I haven't done anything" but then detail (still too briefly) some attempt at using a file reader, and say that you are "unable to get a working script", which implies that you did at least ***try*** to write something that doesn't work.... **That's what we want to see;  we can help figure out what went wrong with your failed attempt.**

Comment: Ok, i understand, tomorrow (right now is night here) i will post the code

Comment: I mean, if you are using FileReader correctly, it should be creating an `ArrayBuffer` which holds your data, and you should be able to use that as the source data for your QR Code.  It isn't a complex process, and should be easy to troubleshoot.

Comment: Ok, thanks Claies, tomorrow i will ping you

Answer (score 0):

ok, i handled correctly:

```
$("#pwbutton").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var file = document.getElementById('customFile').files[0];

  var fr = new FileReader();

  fr.onloadend = function(e) {
    console.log(e.target.result);
    var readed = e.target.result;

    var QRC = qrcodegen.QrCode;
    var segs = qrcodegen.QrSegment.makeSegments(String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint8Array(e.target.result)));
    var qr = QRC.encodeSegments(segs, QRC.Ecc.LOW, 19, 19, -1, true);
    var canvas = document.getElementById("qrcode-canvas");
    qr.drawCanvas(3, 0, canvas);

    $('#qresult').show();
  };

  fr.readAsArrayBuffer(file);


});
```

Comment: You should use `QrSegment.makeBytes()`. Don't hack around with `String.fromCharCode()`.